# Excel - count text occurrences if string is present in adjacent column

Tags: excel, windows

I'm trying to count values in Column A if Column B matches a certain string of text.

```
       assets           status
    -----------------------------
  1 | itemThing    |     yes
  2 |              |     
  3 | itemThing    |
  4 |              |
  5 | itemThing    |     yes
```

This above example would ideally return `2`.

I want to count how many times "item" shows up in column A **ONLY** if column B says "yes"

I've tried something with `=SUMPRODUCT` but it doesn't seem to work correctly. It is currently returning 4 when there are 5 matching criteria.

I have `=SUMPRODUCT((assets=A1)*(status=B1))` where assets and status are custom names for the column ranges created with Name Manager.

Edit: noticed that is has to be an exact string match for it to count correctly. How do I do partial string matches? e.g. search terms? e.g. match `=SUMPRODUCT((assets="*item*")*(status=B1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Two ways here for your reference:

1. `SUMPRODUCT`:

   `=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*itemThing*",assets)))*(status="yes"))`
2. `COUNTIFS`:

   `=COUNTIFS(status,"yes",assets,"*itemThing*")`

For partial match, use wild card `*` such as `"*itemThing*"` and that should do the trick for you.

Comment: The `COUNTIFS` solution worked for me, but the `SUMPRODUCT` did not.

Comment: @Drkumar, if you want, you can show me what the error message is for `SUMPRODUCT` and I can see if I can figure out the issue.